# WIFI stopped working after kernel upgrade!

Tags: wireless, kernel, kubuntu

I logged into my PC as usual and wifi was working as intended, I saw a notification about a system update and how a reboot was required. I followed instruction and rebooted, now my WIFI is no longer working. I've tried rfkill unblock all and restarting, neither have worked.

How do I go about fixing this?

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list  of the kernel with WIFI:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008f]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list  of the kernel with no WIFI:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008f]
    Kernel modules: ath9k
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Texas Instruments XIO2213A/B/XIO2221 PCI Express to PCI Bridge [Cheetah Express] [104c:823e] (rev 01)

 0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

modinfo ath9k: https://pastebin.com/raw/TfaUa6aJ

Comment: Assuming you got a kernel update (there was one this week) and assuming that is what is killing your wifi, you can boot into the prior kernel and see if it works there.  There are a plethora of posts on this stack explaining how to boot into an old kernel.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Booting into the previous kernel fixed it, thanks @OrganicMarble ⁽ ´◡`⁾

Comment: Just to be clear, you'd likely want to be using the most up-to-date kernel.  While it's great you've found a temporary solution, be sure to try to get your wireless working with the new kernel, as well.

Comment: Did you install your own drivers or firmware for your wireless device? If so, then you need to reinstall the firmware after you do a kernel update. Please edit your question to include the information requested by @Pilot6. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't put solved in the title and the answer in the question. The "Your Answer" window is for the solution to the problem. Please answer your own question and accept it as correct. This will help others.

Comment: @mchid my system (kubuntu 18.10) has updated its kernel a few times before, but this is the first version that has disabled WIFI. I've posted the relevant information!

Comment: It is either a kernel regression, or the kernel wasn't fully upgraded. What does `sudo apt upgrade` show?

Comment: @Pilot6 `sudo apt upgrade` led me through some updates then eventually I was told to `sudo apt --fix-broken install` (I did all of this on the working kernel), I assume this is where the problem lies. I rebooted after that, but still the same results. Do I wait until I get 4.18.0-17-generic or can I do something about the failed kernel?

Comment: Did you install any wireless drivers recently?

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't believe I have, WI-FI has been working since installation, I haven't tweaked with it.

Comment: Then maybe some part of the kernel didn't install. Did you run `sudo apt install -f`? It may fix it.

Comment: I tried `sudo apt install -f --reinstall linux-image-4.18.0-16-generic` and rebooting, still no victory there.

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-16-generic`

Comment: Post output of `modinfo ath9k`.

Comment: `modinfo ath9k` added to op, `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-16-generic` reports "is already the newest version (4.18.0-16.17)."